# S3 based Video is not playing in any Mobile Browser using HTML 5 Player or VideoJs Library

Tags: html5-video, mp4, mobile-browser

Video File located on S3 & Trying to play on a Browser using. Video Codecs: MPEG-4 AAC, H.264

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls
       width="640px" height="267px"
       preload="none" data-setup='{ "aspectRatio":"640:267", "playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2] }'>
    <source id="videoMp4" src="{{ $videoName }}.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source id="videoWebm" src="{{ $videoName }}.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source id="videoOgg" src="{{ $videoName }}.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Solution for this, Really tired

Comment: _"Video File located on S3"_ If you mean Amazon S3 then how to reproduce your issue? My MP4 on S3 storage works fine on Android's Chrome browser. **(1)** Type a direct link into your phone and tell us what you see. Either it's the video or it's an XML printout with some error message. **(2)** Amazon S3 is **case-sensitive** so make sure your file name in code matches the stored S3 filename (with matching capital letters, etc)... **(3)** This might not be a code issue (_ie:_ did you set the file to allow "Public" access in your control panel?)...